# UIScrollView not responding to touches

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview, touches

I have an UIScrollView in which I display tweets. The scrollView is contained in a stack of views, the last of which has 4 gesture recognizers.

The scrollView is populated as follows:

```
- (void) createTimeLine:(NSArray*)timeline
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 463, 150);
    NSInteger i = 0;
    NSLog(@"timeline objects: %d", timeline.count);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(463, timeline.count * 150);
    for (NSDictionary *d in timeline) {
        SingleTwitViewController *c = [[SingleTwitViewController alloc] initWithAsingleTwit:d];
        rect.origin.y = i * 150;
        c.view.frame = rect;
        [scrollView addSubview:c.view];
        [scrollView bringSubviewToFront:c.view];
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

There are 20 objects in the timeline, and the first 4 are visible. However, the scrollView does not scroll and the touches are handeled by the gesture recognisers.

The `scrollEnabled` property is set to YES, but for some reason this does not seem to work.

The contentSize is set to 463 * 3000 which is much less than the scrollView it self, but still it won't scroll.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you set the `userInteractionEnable` to `YES` for your scrollView and for your subView?

Answer (score 0):

try these ,

```
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

the content size should be greater than that of scrollView frame size...
so set the content size greater...

Answer (score 0):

I also found a `UIScrollView` inside a simple view (part of the `UIViewController`) not responding to the touch events, even with the `scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true` (regardless of the scrollView.contentSize). In a clean single-view project

This problem is not exactly as in the question above, but I found it interesting to see that my scrollView responds to scroll touches, but not to simple touches.

I decided to subclass the scroll view and add a protocol as follows:

```
protocol XXScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidReportTouchesBegan()
}
class XXScrollView: UIScrollView {  
    var touchDelegate: XXScrollViewDelegate?    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.touchDelegate?.scrollViewDidReportTouchesBegan()
    }
}
```

Do not forget to declare the protocol in the main view, and set the delegate (note that I used a different name to avoid overriding the delegate property of the UIScrollView.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, XXScrollViewDelegate {

scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
scrollView.touchDelegate = self
```

This solves the issue for me, but I am still curious on the reason why it does not respond as expected.